# How do you strip gaps between HTML tags with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Say I have this kind of markup:

```html
<li>    Some text </li>
<li> <strong>  Some text </strong> hello</li>
```

I need to ensure that there is no whitespace gap after the opening `<li>` tag and before any enclosed text content. What is the best way to accomplish this with Nokogiri?

Desired result:

```html
<li>Some text </li>
<li><strong>Some text </strong> hello</li>
```

Comment: Is you markup valid XML, or just HTML? Do you want all whitespace to go, or just inside specific tags?

Comment: It's HTML. I just want the leading whitespace removed, not any other whitespace.

Comment: From every element, or just `<li>`?

Comment: Just li is fine for now.

Answer (score 7):

Removing all leading/trailing whitespace in the whole doc:

```
doc.xpath('//text()').each do |node|
  if node.content=~/\S/
    node.content = node.content.strip
  else
    node.remove
  end
end
```

However, note that this will turn `<p>Hello <b>World</b></p>` into `<p>Hello<b>World</b></p>`. You likely need to more precisely specify what you want.

**Edit:** Here's a better solution that removes leading space from all text nodes that are the first child of an element, and all trailing space from text nodes that are the last child:

```
doc.xpath('//text()[1]').each{ |t|      t.content = t.content.lstrip }
doc.xpath('//text()[last()]').each{ |t| t.content = t.content.rstrip }
```

Seen in action:

```
html = '<ul>
  <li>    First text </li>
  <li> <strong>  Some text </strong> </li>
  <li> I am <b>  embedded  </b> and need <i>some </i>  <em>spaces</em>. </li>
</ul>'

require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.HTML(html)
doc.xpath('//text()[1]').each{ |t|      t.content = t.content.lstrip }
doc.xpath('//text()[last()]').each{ |t| t.content = t.content.rstrip }
puts doc.root
#=> <html><body><ul>
#=> <li>First text</li><li><strong>Some text</strong></li>
#=>   <li>I am <b>embedded</b> and need <i>some</i>  <em>spaces</em>.</li></ul></body></html>
```

**Edit #2:** Here's how to strip it just off text nodes at the front of `<li>`:

```
doc.xpath('//li/text()[1]').each{ |t| t.content = t.content.lstrip }
```

Comment: I've edited my answer at the bottom to match your clarified requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You would traverse each li removing leading whitespace until you find some text:

```
doc.css('li').each do |li|
    li.traverse do |node|
        node.content = node.content.gsub(/^\s+/,'')
        break unless node.content.empty?
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When manipulating a `Nokogiri::HTML.fragment`, the `xpath("//text()")` doesn't seem to work.

So here's what I came up with

```
doc.traverse do |node|
  if node.is_a? Nokogiri::XML::Text
    node.content = node.content.lstrip if node.previous_element&.description&.block?
    node.content = node.content.lstrip if node.previous_element.nil? && node.parent.description&.block?
    node.content = node.content.rstrip if node.next_element&.description&.block?
    node.content = node.content.rstrip if node.next_element.nil? && node.parent.description&.block?
    node.remove if node.content.empty?
  end
end
```

*Note:* uses Ruby 2.3 syntax